# Event tracking especially on Emails google analytics not working

Tags: email, events, google-analytics

Good day all, I am trying to place this image in some emails I am sending out to track if the emails are opened and images are downloaded.

Image with source: src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-########-#&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=openmail&cm=email"

However no events are triggered on google analytics when the image is downloaded, could this be because of a syntax error in the image URL ?

All other google analytics campaigns such as page view tracking still works fine.

Comment: did you try testing your link in the debug end point? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits

Comment: DalmTo thank you so much. There was some problems with my Hit payload, The hit builder worked great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, it doesn't include a `cid` parameter which is required. You can add `debug` to the hit and see the status message returned through your browser. Alternatively you could try the Google Hit Builder to validate/build your hit.

Comment: Thank you a lot, yes I added the cid and it worked great.

Comment: The "Google Hit Builder" completely saved my life: I had an almost impossible typo to detect